# raise at ExceptAddr not working for x64-debugger

Tags: debugging, delphi, exception, delphi-10.4-sydney, delphi-11-alexandria

I use Delphi's `raise at <address>` feature to find the origin of a re-raised exception while debugging.

While this does work under 32 bit, the x64 debugger always shows the line where the exception is re-raised.

Minimal Example:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

begin
  try
    raise Exception.Create('Test'); // this line should be where the debugger breaks
  except
    var E := AcquireExceptionObject;
    raise E at ExceptAddr; // for x64, the debugger breaks here
  end;
end.
```

I tested this with Delphi 10.4 and 11.

Did I misunderstand the `raise at` incorrectly?

Is this a bug, or maybe settings related?

Comment: I also tested the maybe more common "raise at ReturnAddress", which does work under 32 bit and does not work under 64 bit as well.

Comment: Exceptions are quite different in x64 from x86. In the latter they use tables, and in the former the stack. I expect this is why the debugger is different. Does the behave outside the debugger work as expected, referring to the duplicate.